# NIntegrate with variable in it

Tags: numerical-integration, series-expansion

I would like to `NIntegrate` with a variable in the function. Later I will be series expanding it. Can it be done in Matehematica? I am getting errors for a sample integration as,

`NIntegrate[Series[Cosh[x]*Exp[-z*Cosh[x]], {z, 0, 2}], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]`

The error is,

`NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Cosh[x]-Cosh[x]^2 z+1/2 Cosh[x]^3 z^2+O[z]^3 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.}}.`

Is there a way out? I know that, analytically, I can obtain expressions in terms of modified Bessel functions of second kind. But Mathematica does not pick that up.

Comment: Numerical procedures require the numerical values for all variables. Thus, you can't assign the Infinity as a boundary.

Comment: The integral diverges for all real z. You can see that by doing `ser = Normal[Series[Cosh[x]*Exp[-z*Cosh[x]], {z, 0, 2}]];
res = Integrate[ser, x];
Limit[res, x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> Element[z, Reals]]
` or by plotting `res` for different values of `z`.

Comment: I think your integral has the value `BesselK[1,z]`. You should be able to verify this numerically.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand the question, you ask about the asymptotic of the integral $$\int_0^\infty \cosh (x) \exp (-z \cosh (x))\,dx $$ as $z\to 0$ and/or $z->\infty$.
Unfortunately, Mathematica 12.3 fails with that integral: `Integrate[Cosh[x] Exp[-z Cosh[x]], {x, 0, \[Infinity]},  Assumptions -> z > 0]` returns the input. The integral under consideration can be calculated numerically by

```
f[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cosh[x] Exp[-z Cosh[x]], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
f[0.01]
```

> `99.9739`

Unfortunatelly, the `Series` command does not work with `f[z]`. One may investigate the asymptotic of `f[z]` as `z` tends to `0` from above in such a way

```
Table[f[Exp[-k]]/Exp[k], {k, 1, 20}]
```

> `{0.887927, 0.975973, 0.995517, 0.999226, 0.999873, 0.99998, 0.999997, \ 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}`

The above result suggests that `f[z]` is asymptotically equal to `1/z` as `z` approaches `0` from above. I think this can be proven by [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) which is not currently implemented in Mathematica.